# Bind to property before property is initialized

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have a class `Project` that I'm loading via serialization. I'm storing an instance of this class in a property `LoadedProject`.  I'm attempting to bind a label to a property of Project called `ProjectName`.  Until serialization is complete `LoadedProject` is null.

I understand I have to set the DataContext for PropertyChanged to not be null, but setting the DataContext before serialization results in DataContext being null. Setting it after serialization misses the event.

If I'm binding to a child property, where should I set the DataContext if the parent is null?

Project class:

```
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _projectFilePath;

    internal string ProjectFilePath 
    { 
        get { return _projectFilePath; }
        set
        {
            _projectFilePath = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ProjectName");
        }
    }

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get { return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ProjectFilePath); }
    }

    internal static Project Load(string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Project));
            return ds.ReadObject(stream) as Project;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Main.xaml.cs

```
private Project LoadedProject { get; set; }
...
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    // Open document 
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    DataContext = LoadedProject;  //LoadedProject is currently null. Assigning the DataContext here will not work
    LoadedProject = Project.Load(filename);
}
...
```

XAML:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Path=ProjectName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue='No Project Loaded'}"></Label>
```

**Edit 1:** 
Must bind to public properties. Changed ProjectName from internal to public. Initial binding now works. PropertyChanged still null.

Comment: How about `DataContext = Project.Load(filename);`? Otherwise `LoadedProject` should be a property in another view model class.

Comment: @Clemens The propertychange event is fired during serialization, at which point the DataContext is still null. Assigning DataContext after load will still miss the propertychange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your LoadedProject is private, this will certainly cause some binding issues. First ensure that the property is set to public.

```
public Project LoadedProject { get; set; }
```

Assuming that you are binding directly to the LoadedProject property, you simply need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on this property:

```
private Project _LoadedProject;

    public Project LoadedProject
    {
        get { return _LoadedProject; }
        set 
        { 
            _LoadedProject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LoadedProject");
        }
    }
```

This will force your UI to refresh the bindings to this object when it is loaded.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I'm binding my label to LoadedProject.ProjectName.  How does adding OnPropertyChanged to the LoadedProject set event fix that?

Comment: @Brandon Because the xaml will actually make two bindings behind the scenes a binding to `LoadedProject` then a 2nd binding to "the object the first binding is bound to" `.ProjectName`. So if any item in the tree raises property changed it will refresh all of the children. However because `LoadedProject` is in your Main.xaml.cs you likely want to make it a [DependancyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of implementing INotiifyPropertyChange

Comment: Acutally it would require a few more changes. Your DataContext needs to be set to `this` and your xaml changed to `{Binding Path=LoadedProject.ProjectName, .....`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Making both the changes in the answer and your comment, PropertyChanged in both the Project class and the Main.xaml.cs are null. I'm setting DataContext=this just prior to Project.Load()

Comment: Alternatively, you can give your parent element an x:Name attribute and use an ElementName binding such as: {Binding LoadedProject.ProjectName, ElementName=elementName}   This has the same effect as setting the DataContext to itself.

Comment: @MikeEason It got me about 60% of the way there. Still don't know exactly why it failed. I ended up using a BindableBase class from here: http://danrigby.com/2012/04/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way-revisited/.  Btw, I don't believe the asker is notified about comments unless you comment on their question or use the "@username" reference.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to populate the Project outside of the view/viewmodel it is bound to

you could move the label to a sub view/control or have some start up logic